# Trying to open and Read PDF file in c# in uwp

Tags: c#, pdf, c#-4.0, uwp, uwp-xaml

In UWP, file is opening with file picker and stored into storage file. And it can be turned into PdfDocument. It's going good if the pdf file is normal. But It's not well for password protected PDF Document. How to ask User, the password of PDF and open safely.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PdfDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.pdf.pdfdocument) contains the `IsPasswordProtected` property:

> True if the Portable Document Format (PDF) document is password-protected; otherwise, false.

So get this property if it is true, password required to open PDF safely.

```
if (pdfDocument.IsPasswordProtected)
{
    rootPage.NotifyUser("Document is password protected.", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
}
else
{
    rootPage.NotifyUser("Document is not password protected.", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
}
```

More details please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PdfDocument).